# How I open a UIViewController from iOS and Android on forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

Click on a button on forms view and:

## if iOS

open a UIViewController from iOS storyboard

## if Droid

The same for android.

Actually, I need just for iOS...

Answer (score 1):

Usually you just define some interface in your PCL project, and implement it in platform-specific projects linking them using DependencyService.
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/